# How can i delete home?

Tags: magento-1.9

**I see 2 index page in google search result and duplicate my index**

1. mysite . com
2. mysite . com/home

   > i need to deleted the /home
   >   How can i do؟

Comment: `/home` is from the URL you set for the CMS page being shown on `Home`- you could change this URL to something else, but it will still show same contents as home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great article [HERE](https://www.measureddesigns.com/magento-301-redirect-home-url-root/) that shows a simple solution.  Just add a rewrite in `Catalog->URL Rewrite Management` with the following specifications:

```
Type: Custom 
ID Path: home 
Request Path :home 
Target Path: ../
```